# Process id / Window handle late binding in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, com, late-binding

I got a problem regarding late binding, and hope there is someone who can help me.
I have searched Google dry regarding my issue, and most solution do not fit at all.

I am binding a Excel macro written in VBA to my own program to communicate, it works fine with GetObject(). However GetObject() gets a random instance, and I don't want that since there can be multiple instances open at the same time. 
When I open the Excel through a C# program, I pass the window handle and process ID of the newly opened instance as arguments to the excel.

How can I do a late binding in Excel VBA by only using either process ID and / or window handle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vba4all all these are C# examples.. How will I add these in a Excel VBA macro? Did you read my question at all????

Comment: Ok look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288902) and [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=271384)